# In javascript I get error ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error in JavaScript

```
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add more info.  What is this code?  Yours?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?  Please upvote or accept an answer if so.

Answer (score 0):

i think typeof to be used as

```
if(typeof Sys== "undefined")
```

Answer (score 0):

Triple equals, `===`, in javascript is to test for the same type or object.

Change it to double equals, `==` instead.  This will test for the value instead of object equality.

Possible duplicate of these questions:

- [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)
- [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)
- Also [this site](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) really explains `===` well.